# NullReferenceException when checking variable is Null

Tags: c#, wpf

I get this weird NullReferenceExcpetion, in a WPF application. I don't get this every time, even if I do same operation. Can anyone please explain the reason for this,

[image]

```
 public class AmazonUrl
 {
        public string Url { get; set; }
 }

 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {

    public ObservableCollection<AmazonUrl> AmazonUrlList { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = this;
        AmazonUrlList = new ObservableCollection<AmazonUrl>();
    }

    public List<string> getURLList()
    {
        List<string> urlList = new List<string>();

        for(int i = 0; i < AmazonUrlList.Count; i++)
        {
            AmazonUrl url = AmazonUrlList[i];

            if (url == null)
                continue;

            String str = url.Url.ToString().Trim();

            if (str.Length > 0)
               urlList.Add(str);
       }

       return urlList;
   }

    private void openMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> urlList = getURLList();//This is where exception occur

        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Filter = "SCR File (.scr)|*.scr|All Files|*.*";

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() != true){ ... }
    }
```

Note: After adding these lines I made lots of changes to the application, and recompiled several times. So this is not a problem with Build or Compiling

Edit: My stack trace can find from here, https://pastebin.com/2vyH1qah

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: Stack trace would be useful - my money is on an overridden operator == causing the issue.

Comment: I wonder if it's pointing to the wrong line.  I've had that happen if the debug files are out of date.

Comment: Is that definitely *all* that's in the `AmazonUrl` class? Are you able to reproduce this with a [mcve]?

Comment: I updated the question detail, I added the call stack. Did you ask that?

Comment: @maamaa we need the exception stack trace, not the call stack. It should be printed to the Output window.

Comment: Yes, all of the AmazonURL  body is this. But inside the MainWindow there are several methods. And I'm not using any threads at this point

Comment: You might consider changing your condition slightly: `if (url == null || string.IsNullOrWhitespace(url.Url)) continue;` This saves you from having to check the `.Length` later, after your call to `Trim()`. You also don't need to call `ToString()` on `url.Url`, since it's already a `string`.

Comment: @Defenestrator I'm sorry, you can find it in here, https://pastebin.com/2vyH1qah

Comment: @maama, could you pls paste the implementation of AmazonUrl class?

Comment: Your whole method could be simplified to: `return AmazonUrlList.Where(url => url != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url.Url)).Select(url => url.Url.Trim()).ToList();`

Comment: @maamaa According to your stack trace, this very much looks like a threading issue. Are you sure that you're not using threading? Or maybe you're using a library that uses threading?

Comment: @Defenestrator I'm using a BakgroundWorker, but at this point its not even started. And I'm not using any other external libaries. There is "Open" GUI Button in my application, I just started my application and clicked on that, then I get this exception. (And the BackgroundWorkers start only if I click some two other buttons). And I updated code to include the Open Button event handling code.

Comment: What's the purpose of the AmazonUrl class when it only has the Url property? You could as well simply have a collection of strings instead.

Comment: @Clemens: I'm using a DataGrid, which has only one column. I'm using AmazonURLList as the Item source for it.

Comment: @maamaa you can use a collection of strings as a source too, you just need to define the column header yourself in xaml

Comment: My guess is the collection is modified while in the loop

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the error, it must be something with your collection. What does your collection look like?
This should fix the problem either way--

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private static object lockObj = new object(); //Add
```

...

```
public List<string> getURLList()
  {
     List<string> urlList = new List<string>();

     for (int i = 0; i < AmazonUrlList.Count; i++)
     {
        Amazon url = new AmazonUrl();  // Add
        url = AmazonUrlList[i];        // Update
```

...

```
private void openMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     lock (lockObj) // Add
     {
        List<string> urlList = getURLList(); //This is where exception occur
     }
```